# Custom migration fails in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to follow this super simple README guide when installing pg-trgm gem for my Rails app (https://github.com/mitchellhenke/sequel-pg-trgm)

Unfortunately, I must be doing something wrong as I get error message:

```
== 20180531122444 AddPgTrgmExtensionToDb: migrating ===========================
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `plugin' for #<Class:0x007fdb68c1bad8>
```

I imagine this is about the `plugin` im trying to use in my model for this migration, but I have no idea why this is a problem.

My migration file:

```
class AddPgTrgmExtensionToDb < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
  Card.migration do
  up do
    extension :pg_trgm
    add_pg_trgm(:foods, :name)
  end

  down do
    extension :pg_trgm
    drop_pg_trgm(:foods, :name)
  end
  end
  end
end
```

My model file:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  plugin :pg_trgm
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `plugin` on model `Card`?

Comment: Hey @JagdeepSingh I wasn't sure - I was following the tutorial. But the answer below solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [gem](https://github.com/mitchellhenke/sequel-pg-trgm) you are referring to is for *Sequel* and not for *Rails* AR so this will not work.

You can execute custom SQL using the `execute` method in your Migrations. That should allow you to create those trm indexes.
Please note that if you use `execute` then you might want to switch the way Rails records your schema from `schema.rb` to `structure.sql`. See the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you) for details

Another solution is the [pg_search gem](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) mentioned in the comments by @sparkAP

Comment: Much appreciated. For anybody learning Ruby / Rails, I suggest using https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search - has the trigram function and is much easier to implement without having to change schema.rb etc. (found it a few minutes after this answer was posted)

Comment: @sparkAP I added the pg_search gem to the answer, thanks for commenting.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction. Still learning Rails / DB / Ruby basics, so every piece of knowledge is useful. Have a great week(end)!